# Reemplazar texto excepto en divs de una clase con expresion regular

Tags: php, regex

Necesito una expresión regular que me reemplace un texto que esté fuera de un determinado div.

Ejemplo:

```
<div class="try">foo</div>
<div>foo</div>
foo
<span>foo</span>
```

La salida debería ser al reemplazar foo por bar:

```
<div class="try">foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
bar
<span>bar</span>
```

https://regex101.com/r/3OZbyf/1

Comment: Quieres reemplazar todos los foo por ejemplo que están fuera de <div class="try"></div>?
Ah, y en que lenguaje estás trabajando? Porque todos los lenguajes no tienen la mismas caracteristicas de expresiones regulares. Algunos lenguajes carecen de ciertas cosas.

Comment: Lorthas estoy trabajando en PHP

Comment: ¿Cuál es propósito del enlace? ¿Has buscado/investigado? Por favor, sigue el [tour] y lee [ask] para informarte del funcionamiento básico de este sitio.

Comment: Buenas Rubén, Si he preguntado es porque he investigado y no entiendo bien el uso de la negación en expresiones regulares. El propósito del enlace es donde he intentado hacerla pero no me ha salido, quien intente ayudarme por lo menos tiene el texto para hacer pruebas.

Comment: No se puede hacer con regex. Tienes que usar DOMParser

Comment: Por si acaso
https://regex101.com/r/3OZbyf/3
Pero tiene que ser muy específico con un numero de espacios muy especifico y tiene que ser solo un espacio seguido justo por class="try">
Sino no va a funcionar. Ya que con las expresiones regulares no permite por lo visto usar cuantificadores dentro de un lookbehind.
Mejor hacer lo que dice @amenadiel.
Con Javascript probablemente se puede hacer facilmente, no?

Comment: Claro, javascript entiende nativamente el concepto de anidación del html. Regex en cambio trabaja sobre sintaxis regulares, no entiende una sintaxis libre como xml ni html salvo en casos anecdóticos.

Comment: @Mariano Oh! Bueno, supuse que al no haber una con un nombre en Español (Como la comunidad), seria bueno tener la etiqueta (con nombre en Español) ya que algunos podrian conocerlas como _Expresiones Regulares_ y mas bien en su lugar, crear un sinonimo. que redirija a _regex_

Comment: @Mariano Cuando busqué, la etiqueta que tu creaste, no la encontré (seguro algún problema de navegador), fue por ello que decidí crearla.

Answer (score 2):

No deberías usar expresiones regulares para procesar HTML. Tan sólo un pequeño cambio en el HTML haría que tu regex falle. Un espacio de más, un cambio en los atributos del tag, un comentario, o estructuras más complejas, harían que hasta un regex gigantesco no siga las reglas.

Es muy sencillo procesar HTML con **[DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)**, son las herramientas que están pensadas para eso.

Simplemente se genera el DOM así:

```php
//Ingreso
$html = '
<div class="try">foo</div>
<div>foo</div>
foo
<span>foo</span>'

//Generar el DOM
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_NONET);
```

Tomando el body del documento generado:

```php
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
```

Y podemos recorrer todos los nodos hijos:

```php
foreach ($nodoDOM->childNodes as $nodo) {
```

Reemplazando en los nodos de texto:

```php
if ($nodo->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
    $nodo->nodeValue = str_ireplace( $buscar, $reemplazo, $nodo->nodeValue);
}
```

O buscando recursivamente en los nodos que no tienen la clase `"try"`:

```php
if( !$nodo->hasAttributes()
 || !in_array("try", explode(" ", $nodo->getAttribute("class"))) ) {
```

---

### Código

```php
<?php

//Ingreso
$html = '
<div class="try">foo</div>
<div>foo</div>
foo
<span>foo</span>';

echo "TEXTO ORIGINAL:" . $html;


//Generar el DOM
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_NONET);
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);


//Reemplazar recursivamente
$html = buscarNodoDOM($body, "foo", "bar", "try");

function buscarNodoDOM(DOMNode $nodoDOM, $buscar, $reemplazo, $claseProhibida, $recursivo = false) {
    $resultado = "";

    //recorrer todos los nodos
    foreach ($nodoDOM->childNodes as $nodo) {

        if ($nodo->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            //Si es un nodo de texto, reemplazar
            $nodo->nodeValue = str_ireplace( $buscar, $reemplazo, $nodo->nodeValue);
        } elseif(( !$nodo->hasAttributes() || !in_array($claseProhibida, explode(" ", $nodo->getAttribute("class"))) )
              && $nodo->hasChildNodes()) {
            //si no es de la clase prohibida, y tiene hijos, recorrer todos los hijos
            buscarNodoDOM($nodo, $buscar, $reemplazo, $claseProhibida, true);
        }

        if (!$recursivo) {
            //si estamos en el body, agregar todo el HTML del nodo al resultado
            $resultado .= $nodoDOM->ownerDocument->saveHTML($nodo);
        }
    }
    //devolver el HTML como texto
    return $resultado;
}



//Mostrar resultado
echo "\n\nTEXTO MODIFICADO:\n" . $html;
```

#### Resultado:

```
TEXTO ORIGINAL:
<div class="try">foo</div>
<div>foo</div>
foo
<span>foo</span>
```

```
TEXTO MODIFICADO:
<div class="try">foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
bar
<span>bar</span>
```

#### Demo:

[<kbd>Ver la demo en 3v4l.org</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/JSeV5)